# Zend2 without Virtual Host

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, virtualhost

I have Zend2 website configured on an Ubuntu machine.
Project Path: `/var/www/zf2/`

Virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zf2.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf2/public
SetENV APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /var/www/html/zf2/public/>
DirectoryIndex index.php
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing "localhost/zf2" list the files in the directory. Is there anyway to access this zend2 website without virtual host i.e with localhost/zf2 ?
I already tried by adding .htacess in `/var/www/html/zf2`, but it does not budge. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you use mod_rewrite to send all requests for localhost/zf2 to localhost/zf2/public, which is the root of the site?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't very clear, but if you're asking if it's possible for someone to access your ZF site without using the `zf2.localhost` hostname, then because of the way you have set it up, *yes* (and you should definitely change this).

By default, Apache on Ubuntu has localhost setup to point at `/var/www/html/`. So by putting your ZF2 app in a subfolder of that, it will be possible for someone to access your ZF app (including files outside of its document root) via. localhost. This is a potential security hole which you should fix. Simply move your ZF2 app to a different folder that isn't inside `/var/www/html` (e.g. `/var/www/zf2`) and you won't have this issue.

Also note that if you are using a reasonably recent version of Ubuntu, you will be running Apache 2.4, and your vhost isn't setup correctly. See the second example here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/installation.html#apache-setup

Comment: Yes, I want to access my Zend 2 site without the virtual host (zf2.localhost) i.e simply by going to localhost/zf2.
Currently my zend2 resides inside /var/www/html/zf2 and is accessible via virtual host zf2.localhost.